# Email changes input's CSS styling

Tags: php, javascript, css, forms

I have created a contact form using labels as a type of place holder, putting them behind the input box with a transparent background then making background white on `:focus` and setting the background white when value of input is > 0.

I have recently incorporated the necessary PHP into my form which has destroyed my styling. I have recovered it slightly but don't understand why the inputs are a few pixels too long. It changes the styling as soon as I put the PHP above the doctype declaration.

I do not know what to do about the page's label showing through on page refresh. [Have a look][1] and see what you think. How can I get it working smoothly?

[Here is a JSFiddle showing my contact form styling][2].

Here is my php

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false){
    $errors = array();

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    if (empty($name) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($message) === true) {
        $errors[] = 'Name, email and message are required!';
    } else {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Invalid email address';
        }
        if (ctype_alpha($name) === false) {
            $errors[] = 'Name must contain letters only';
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        mail('mailmattysmith@gmail.com', 'Contact form', $message, 'From: ' . $email);
        header('Location: index.php?sent');
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Matthew Smith | Contact</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #contact_btn{
            border-bottom: 5px solid #0af !important; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php 
        include("header.php");
    ?>

    <div id="wrapper">
        <img class="click_contact" id="logo" src="img/logo1.png">
        <br><p id="contact_me" class="quote">Get In touch</p>
        <div id="contact_form">
            <?php
                if (isset($_GET['sent']) === true) {
                    echo '<p>Thanks for contacting me</p>';
                } else {

                    if (empty($errors) === false) {
                        echo '<ul>';
                        foreach ($errors as $error) {
                        echo '<li>', $error, '</li>';
                    }
                        echo '</ul>';
                }
            ?>

            <form action="" method="post" >
                <div class="input_wrap" id="first">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" <?php if (isset($_POST['name']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['name']), '"'; } ?>>
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input_wrap">
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" <?php if (isset($_POST['email']) === true) { echo 'value="', strip_tags($_POST['email']), '"'; } ?>>
                    <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                </div>
                <div class="input_wrap">
                    <input>
                    <label>Subject</label>
                </div>
                <div class="input_wrap" id="last">
                    <textarea name="message" id="message"><?php if (isset($_POST['message']) === true) { echo strip_tags($_POST['message']), ''; } ?></textarea>
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" id="send" value="Send">
            </form>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="footer"><p>&#169; Matt Smith <?php echo date('Y'); ?></p></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#logo').click(function(){

                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $(".quote").offset().top
                    }, 1000);                  


                 });


    $('input, textarea').on('keyup', function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if($(this).val().length > 0) {
        $this.css({backgroundColor: '#fff'});
    } else {
        $this.css({backgroundColor: 'transparent'});
    }
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

{[1]: http://www.dominichook.co.uk/matthew/contact.php
{[2]: http://jsfiddle.net/tUnc4/

Comment: No one here can see your php unless you post it. Browsers don't show PHP because PHP is processed before the browser sees a page since it's a sever-side language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your contact form is not the PHP, but actually the way you've coded your labels for the fields. I see that the form submits, and then you do your verification in PHP, then if there is a problem it returns the form with the current values set using the `value` attribute. This is all fine, but you need a way of removing the labels or just use the `placeholder` attribute.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamWalters/cxYju/) using the placeholder attribute.

Comment: i was under the impression that labels are needed in forms and this is a way of incorporating labels that look good as use as placeholders. are labels not needed?

Comment: They're good for accessibility, but as far as I know they're not required. You can also make them hidden, which mean they're there for screen readers but not everyone

Comment: The only Problem i seem to have with placeholders is that you have to start typing for them to hide. i have updated the page with placeholders but how would i reqtify my styling issues?

Comment: I've added a jsfiddle to my answer

Comment: can you correct the input size so it isn't a few pixels to long? that is my main issue at the moment. that issue doesn't exist without the php

Comment: Can you confirm that you don't want the black line down the right side of the inputs?

Comment: its not a black line, its the input box's with a transparent background which seem to be breaking the with, but no i do not want them

Comment: Hi @aztekgold I've simplified your html and css, removed the unnecessary javascript, and fixed the overlap. Please remember to up vote my answer and accept it if it has answered your question. Here's the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GrahamW0009/cxYju/2/)

Comment: Thanks alot! makes a change for someone to actually help

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the [`placeholder`](http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html) attribute instead of your overly complex solution.

For example:

```
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" placeholder="you@example.com" name="email" id="email" />
```

Browser that do not support this attribute will ignore it. You may simulate the effect for older browsers with JavaScript (for example, [Simple-Placeholder](https://github.com/marcgg/Simple-Placeholder)).